# How to find closed objects among an array of lines?

Tags: python, autocad

I have a list of tuples. Each tuple contains coordinate points (x, y, x1, y1,...) forming a line.
All these lines form a drawing.

[image: drawing]

There are 5 closed objects in this picture.
How can I get the number of these objects with their coordinates?

```
Coordinates_list = [(939, 1002, 984, 993, 998, 1001, 1043, 995, 1080, 1004, 1106, 994, 1147, 1003, 1182, 995, 1223, 1005), (939, 1002, 939, 900), (939, 900, 961, 916), (961, 916, 1031, 898), (1031, 898, 1080, 906), (1080, 906, 1190, 896), (1190, 896, 1225, 897), (1223, 1005, 1225, 897), (939, 1002, 1031, 898, 1106, 994, 1190, 896, 1182, 995)]
```

I tried to use the DFS (Depth First Search) Algorithm, but it always returned fewer objects than there actually were. But the data here is presented differently - here there are no more than two points in the tuple, but this does not change the drawing

```
def find_closed_figures(lines):
    def dfs(line_idx, visited):
        visited.add(line_idx)
        for neighbor_idx, line in enumerate(lines):
            if neighbor_idx not in visited and lines[line_idx][3:6] == line[0:3]:
                dfs(neighbor_idx, visited)

    closed_figures_count = 0
    visited_lines = set()
    for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
        if idx not in visited_lines:
            dfs(idx, visited_lines)
            closed_figures_count += 1

    return closed_figures_count

coordinates_list = [(939, 1002, 0, 984, 993, 0), (984, 993, 0, 998, 1001, 0), (998, 1001, 0, 1043, 995, 0), (1043, 995, 0, 1080, 1004, 0), (1080, 1004, 0, 1106, 994, 0), (1106, 994, 0, 1147, 1003, 0), (1147, 1003, 0, 1182, 995, 0), (1182, 995, 0, 1223, 1005, 0), (939, 1002, 0, 939, 900, 0), (939, 900, 0, 961, 916, 0), (961, 916, 0, 1031, 898, 0), (1031, 898, 0, 1080, 906, 0), (1080, 906, 0, 1190, 896, 0), (1190, 896, 0, 1225, 897, 0), (1223, 1005, 0, 1225, 897, 0), (939, 1002, 0, 1031, 898, 0), (1031, 898, 0, 1106, 994, 0), (1106, 994, 0, 1190, 896, 0), (1190, 896, 0, 1182, 995, 0)]


closed_figures_count = find_closed_figures(coordinates_list)
print(closed_figures_count)
```

Comment: You say you tried DFS and your solution didn't return the expected result - please share your code, so we can see what you tried and suggest improvements from there. Also, is there a particular reason for all the coordinates to be in the general 800-1300 range?

Comment: @Grismar, The coordinates can be any. I’ll add the code with the DFS method now

Comment: @Grismar. oh yes, sorry

Comment: The code you shared seems to (more or less) count lines that have some partial overlap, although the tested overlap is curiously 3 coordinates wide. However, there doesn't appear to be anything in the code that looks to complete a shape/object. The list of data you provide defines series of line segments, and a shape seems to be defined as a closed loop formed by a minimal subset of connecting segments. If you need to describe in detail how you would perform the task by hand, that might be a good starting point for a working algorithm.

Comment: Once you structure the problem in a way that can lead to a solution, a DFS doesn't seem like the appropriate choice, since you're not looking for a shape or some path, but you're looking to collect *all* the shapes. It seems to make more sense to identify shapes by chaining together line segments into unique strings of segments.

Comment: @Grismar, but is this possible with the coordinates that I originally wrote in the question? If yes, I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Your problem is essentially to find all the smallest cycles in a planar graph (or network), with a smallest cycle being a cycle that doesn't enclose any other edges. Reducing the 'lines' to a list of vertices and edges is very straightforward. Have you looked at libraries like `networkx` that can help simplify solving a problem on graphs/networks like this? (it's definitely possible, that's clear from the plot alone)

Comment: @Grismar, please write the code, at least a minimal reproducible example

Comment: StackOverflow is not here to write your code for you, it is here to help you fix code that has some specific problem, or help find an appropriate algorithm. It's unclear if you're tasked to write this algorithm yourself, or if you're allowed to use libraries like `networkx`. Your initial attempt is still a long ways away from a working solution - and you don't answer questions that might help guide you towards a solution.

Comment: @Grismar, What specific questions do you have?

Comment: As you can read, only a few lines up: "Have you looked at libraries like `networkx` that can help simplify solving a problem on graphs/networks like this?" and "are you allowed to use to use libraries like `networkx`?"

Comment: @Grismar, we can use any libraries, but I didn’t know about such a library

Comment: I can’t formulate the problem correctly and clearly in my head

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a condensed version of [Grismar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78144939/5242412), where he has a good explanation as well. I just removed the manual search for segments and treated each point as a node directly.

```
import networkx as nx

lines = [
    (939, 1002, 984, 993, 998, 1001, 1043, 995, 1080, 1004, 1106, 994, 1147, 1003, 1182, 995, 1223, 1005),
    (939, 1002, 939, 900),
    (939, 900, 961, 916),
    (961, 916, 1031, 898),
    (1031, 898, 1080, 906),
    (1080, 906, 1190, 896),
    (1190, 896, 1225, 897),
    (1223, 1005, 1225, 897),
    (939, 1002, 1031, 898, 1106, 994, 1190, 896, 1182, 995)
]
point_lists = [[pair for pair in zip(line[::2],line[1::2])] for line in lines]
edges = [segment for point_list in point_lists for segment in zip(point_list[:-1], point_list[1:])]
G = nx.from_edgelist(edges)
cycles = list(nx.chordless_cycles(G))
print('The number of chord-less cycles:', len(cycles))
print('The cycles:')
for cycle in cycles: print("\t", cycle)
```

Comment: `[(0.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 50.0, 50.0, 0.0)]
The number of chord-less cycles: 1
The cycles:
         [(0.0, 50.0), (50.0, 50.0), (50.0, 0.0)]` - looks wrong, right? Because in this example there are two closed areas. that is, two chordless cycles

Comment: @BobbyLith From your data, there is no line segment connecting `(0,0)` and `(0,50)`, and hence there is only one chord-less cycle. If you add that segment, it correctly detects two chord-less cycles.

Comment: I think I understand what you're talking about. Apparently there is a problem with the input data.

Comment: @BobbyLith There is no problem with the question you have asked, but I think there is a mismatch between how you imagined this second example and how you wrote down the coordinates for the corresponding lines. If you draw the said lines, you'll see there is only one one chord-less cycle.

Answer (score 2):

The data you provided is provided as a series of 'lines', which are series of segments from (x, y) pair to (x, y) pair in a plane. You've provided a graphic that corresponds to the data.

Looking at the graphic, it's clear that the data can be seen as a network (or 'graph' as mathematicians would call it) and the problem you're looking to solve is to find all the chord-less cycles in this network. A cycle is a series of points (vertices) in the network that loops back on itself. A chord-less cycles is a cycle so that no line cuts across the cycle - for example, if you combined shape 1 and 2, you'd still have a shape, but it would have a line cutting across it, so it would not be chord-less.

A library like `networkx` has functions that do all the hard work, once you convert your data to an actual graph or network.

Look at this code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, setworldcoordinates
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# the example data
data = [
    (939, 1002, 984, 993, 998, 1001, 1043, 995, 1080, 1004, 1106, 994, 1147, 1003, 1182, 995, 1223, 1005),
    (939, 1002, 939, 900),
    (939, 900, 961, 916),
    (961, 916, 1031, 898),
    (1031, 898, 1080, 906),
    (1080, 906, 1190, 896),
    (1190, 896, 1225, 897),
    (1223, 1005, 1225, 897),
    (939, 1002, 1031, 898, 1106, 994, 1190, 896, 1182, 995)
]


def draw_segments(lines, llx, lly, urx, ury):
    # draw data in the format provided as a turtle graphic
    t = Turtle()

    setworldcoordinates(llx, lly, urx, ury)

    t.hideturtle()
    t.speed(0)

    for line in lines:
        start, rest = line[0:2], line[2:]
        rest = [(rest[i], rest[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(rest), 2)]
        t.penup()
        t.setposition(*start)
        t.pendown()
        for point in rest:
            t.setposition(*point)


def lines_to_segments(lines):
    # breaks up `lines` into unique segments with a start and end point
    result = []
    for line in lines:
        assert len(line) % 2 == 0  # the number of coordinates has to be even for each 'line'
        for i in range(0, len(line) - 2, 2):
            # start always to the left of end, to be able to check for unique segments
            if line[i] < line[i + 2]:
                segment = (line[i], line[i + 1], line[i + 2], line[i + 3])
            else:
                segment = (line[i + 2], line[i + 3], line[i], line[i + 1])
            # only add the segment if it wasn't there already
            if segment not in result:
                result.append(segment)
    return result


def network_from_segments(segments):
    g = nx.Graph()
    for segment in segments:
        g.add_edge((segment[0], segment[1]), (segment[2], segment[3]))
    return g


def main():
    # to see the data as a graphic:
    # draw_segments(data, 800, 800, 1400, 1100)

    # break up the lines into individual edges
    data_segments = lines_to_segments(data)
    # and turn those into a networkx graph
    data_g = network_from_segments(data_segments)

    # show a graphic of the network using matplotlib (optional)
    # nx.draw(data_g, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
    # plt.show()

    print('The network is planar:', nx.is_planar(data_g))

    # all the heavy lifting is here, networkx can find the chord-less cycles
    cycles = list(nx.chordless_cycles(data_g))
    print('The number of chord-less cycles:', len(cycles))
    print('The cycles:')
    for cycle in cycles:
        print(cycle)

    input('Press Enter to continue...')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment out the sections that draw the original graphic or the corresponding network. If you run it as is, it will output the number of 'shapes' or rather chord-less cycles in the graph defined by the data you have.

Just the code that solves the problem:

```
import networkx as nx

data = [
    (939, 1002, 984, 993, 998, 1001, 1043, 995, 1080, 1004, 1106, 994, 1147, 1003, 1182, 995, 1223, 1005),
    (939, 1002, 939, 900),
    (939, 900, 961, 916),
    (961, 916, 1031, 898),
    (1031, 898, 1080, 906),
    (1080, 906, 1190, 896),
    (1190, 896, 1225, 897),
    (1223, 1005, 1225, 897),
    (939, 1002, 1031, 898, 1106, 994, 1190, 896, 1182, 995)
]


def lines_to_segments(lines):
    # breaks up `lines` into unique segments with a start and end point
    result = []
    for line in lines:
        assert len(line) % 2 == 0  # the number of coordinates has to be even for each 'line'
        for i in range(0, len(line) - 2, 2):
            # start always to the left of end, to be able to check for unique segments
            if line[i] < line[i + 2]:
                segment = (line[i], line[i + 1], line[i + 2], line[i + 3])
            else:
                segment = (line[i + 2], line[i + 3], line[i], line[i + 1])
            # only add the segment if it wasn't there already
            if segment not in result:
                result.append(segment)
    return result


def network_from_segments(segments):
    g = nx.Graph()
    for segment in segments:
        g.add_edge((segment[0], segment[1]), (segment[2], segment[3]))
    return g


def main():
    # break up the lines into individual edges
    data_segments = lines_to_segments(data)
    # and turn those into a networkx graph
    data_g = network_from_segments(data_segments)

    # all the heavy lifting is here, networkx can find the chord-less cycles
    cycles = list(nx.chordless_cycles(data_g))
    print('The number of chord-less cycles:', len(cycles))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: the code does not show all closed objects. Where can I add a photo to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @BobbyLith I tested the above code, and the function does return the set of coordinates forming the 5 objects, as you expect.

Comment: @KrishnadevN, if you add another line that forms 6 objects, it still outputs 5 objects. I can send you the input data as an example

Comment: @BobbyLith I have added a condensed version of this code, to avoid any possible errors with the manual loops. You may test that as well with your new/extra set of lines.