# How to find chordless cycles in a drawing?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, charts

The input data is an array of lines consisting of two or more two-dimensional points:

```
coordinates = [(x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2, etc.), (x3, y3, x4, y4, etc.)].
```

Here are all the coordinates: https://pastebin.com/raw/ascwXxKY.

The task is to find all chordless cycles in the figure. You should take into account that a chord can be drawn not only between points of the graph, but also, for example, from the middle of one line to the middle of another.

The cycle may not touch other lines.

You should also keep in mind that a chord can consist of several lines, as shown in the figure below.

There are a total of 15 such cycles in my drawing:

[image: drawing]

I've tried using the chordless loops method from networkx, but so far I haven't found a suitable method specifically for my situation.

Here is a block of code that will help to plot all the lines at the coordinates I specified above:

```
# Create coordinate lists for each pair of points
x_coords = []
y_coords = []
all_connections = []

for coord_set in coordinates:
    x_pair = []
    y_pair = []
    connections_pair = []
    for i in range(len(coord_set) // 2 - 1):
        x1, y1 = coord_set[2*i], coord_set[2*i+1]
        x2, y2 = coord_set[2*i+2], coord_set[2*i+3]
        x_pair.extend([x1, x2])
        y_pair.extend([y1, y2])
        connections_pair.append(((x1, y1), (x2, y2)))
        all_connections.append(((x1, y1), (x2, y2)))
    x_coords.append(x_pair)
    y_coords.append(y_pair)



# Plot the graph
for i in range(len(x_coords)):
    plt.plot(x_coords[i], y_coords[i], marker='o')

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title('Line Chart')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: In your image the small round dots are, I assume, co-ords in the input data.  There are no lines that cross without there being a dot at the crossing i.e. no line crosses or touches another line without the coordinates being present in the input.  Is this GUARANTEED?  If so, it makes things a lot simpler!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all chordless cycles in an undirected graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022662/find-all-chordless-cycles-in-an-undirected-graph)

Comment: Note that the green dot at (90.99670432438654, 95.02694795009378) touches a blue edge -- from (90.78920136958413, 95.02694795009378) to (91.52320136958417, 95.02694795009378) -- halfway . So what do you want to happen there? Split that edge into two separate edges? Or is this inconsistent data?

Comment: Also, the grey edge at the right: (203.66053889808222, 105.03653839839737, 203.66053889808222, 101.03653839839737) .... ***crosses*** the blue line (203.61120136958561, 105.02694795009344, 204.07420136958558, 105.11694795009348). The coordinates of the crossing point are not in your data. Please clarify.

Comment: @trincot, Yes, you correctly noticed that the dots sometimes half touch the lines. It is necessary to create a solution that takes into account such connections to create a cycle.

Comment: @beaker, If you choose cycle methods, cycle_basic or minimal_cycle_basic are more suitable. They show that there are 15 cycles. But even in this case the cycles are calculated incorrectly. There are subcycles inside the obtained cycles.

And the chordless_basic method shows that there are 330 cycles in the drawing. Besides, its execution takes more time.

Comment: @beaker, But if you have a solution to this problem, suggest a working option please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the data set has a couple of edges that intersect (other than at their endpoints), you'd first want to normalise it to a graph that has all these edges split, so the graph does not have such intersections anymore.

In some examples you have given, the edges that are intended to touch eachother actually don't, because of the limited precision in the input data. To counter that, you could adjust the edges that are "dead ends", and make them a tiny bit longer.

After that you can apply the procedure of following neighboring edges by always choosing the one that makes the most left turn (or most right turn). I would duplicate the edges first so they exist in both directions. Then once a directed edge is visited, it can be removed from the graph.

There will be one path that follows the outside of the graph. This one can be excluded on the observation that it completes the circuit in the opposite direction (with relative angles that sum up differently than the other, real area-paths).

Here is code that does not use a graph library:

```
from collections import defaultdict


coords = [(2536.948596571963, 1495.6001088264184, 2537.706596571963, 1491.4401088264185, 2538.720596571963, 1485.6001088264184, 2539.1375965719635, 1483.5001088264185, 2540.6675965719633, 1475.6001088264184, 2541.3665965719633, 1471.9401088264185, 2542.566596571963, 1465.6001088264184, 2543.209596571963, 1462.5601088264184, 2544.727596571963, 1455.6001088264184, 2546.9675965719634, 1446.4701088264185, 2547.1915965719636, 1445.6001088264184, 2549.0705965719635, 1436.4801088264185, 2549.2515965719635, 1435.6001088264184, 2549.3065965719634, 1435.6001088264184, 2549.3115965719635, 1435.6001088264184, 2552.0625965719632, 1435.6001088264184, 2552.3485965719633, 1435.6001088264184, 2554.729596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2555.294596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2557.3605965719635, 1435.6001088264184, 2559.0515965719633, 1435.6001088264184, 2559.9605965719634, 1435.6001088264184, 2561.3875965719635, 1435.6001088264184, 2562.5125965719635, 1435.6001088264184, 2563.7235965719633, 1435.6001088264184, 2564.8165965719636, 1435.6001088264184, 2566.1095965719633, 1435.6001088264184, 2567.5525965719635, 1435.6001088264184, 2568.874596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2570.901596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2572.4065965719633, 1435.6001088264184, 2573.961596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2575.3975965719633, 1435.6001088264184, 2576.2905965719633, 1435.6001088264184, 2578.081596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2579.1065965719636, 1435.6001088264184, 2579.2315965719636, 1435.6001088264184, 2580.4365965719635, 1435.6001088264184, 2580.4465965719633, 1435.6001088264184, 2580.545596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2580.8465965719633, 1435.6001088264184, 2581.147596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2581.440596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2581.723596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2581.913596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2582.232596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2582.502596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2582.857596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2583.247596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2583.612596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2584.059596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2584.4775965719627, 1435.6001088264184, 2584.848596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2585.337596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2585.7265965719625, 1435.6001088264184, 2586.103596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2586.4585965719625, 1435.6001088264184, 2587.013596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2587.371596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2587.684596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2587.946596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2588.185596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2588.770596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2589.032596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2592.299596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2592.6515965719627, 1435.6001088264184, 2592.938596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2593.640596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2593.805596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2593.962596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2594.5305965719626, 1435.6001088264184, 2594.683596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2595.199596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2595.330596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2595.876596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2595.988596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2596.5435965719635, 1435.6001088264184, 2596.6505965719634, 1435.6001088264184, 2597.1995965719634, 1435.6001088264184, 2597.304596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2597.8335965719634, 1435.6001088264184, 2598.327596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2598.433596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2598.8915965719634, 1435.6001088264184, 2599.298596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2599.4085965719632, 1435.6001088264184, 2599.769596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2600.071596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2600.186596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2600.431596571963, 1435.6001088264184, 2612.4455965719626, 1440.3401088264186, 2612.5935965719627, 1440.3401088264186, 2613.1735965719627, 1440.4201088264185, 2613.7825965719626, 1440.5001088264185, 2613.9165965719626, 1440.5001088264185, 2614.5255965719625, 1440.5801088264186, 2614.6675965719623, 1440.5801088264186, 2615.2515965719626, 1440.6601088264188, 2635.4905965719627, 1442.8301088264186, 2635.9525965719627, 1442.8901088264186, 2636.3505965719623, 1442.9401088264185, 2636.6685965719626, 1442.9801088264185, 2636.897596571963, 1443.0101088264184, 2637.0205965719624, 1443.0301088264184, 2637.1845965719626, 1443.0501088264184, 2637.3545965719627, 1443.0701088264184, 2637.4935965719624, 1443.0901088264184, 2637.5665965719627, 1443.1001088264184, 2647.2875965719627, 1445.6001088264184, 2647.322596571963, 1445.6001088264184, 2647.366596571963, 1445.6001088264184, 2647.4235965719627, 1445.6001088264184, 2647.484596571963, 1445.6001088264184, 2647.563596571963, 1445.6001088264184, 2650.223596571963, 1445.6001088264184, 2650.350596571963, 1445.6001088264184, 2650.531596571963, 1445.6001088264184, 2654.813596571963, 1445.6001088264184, 2654.870596571963, 1445.6001088264184, 2654.9325965719627, 1445.6001088264184, 2655.116596571963, 1445.6001088264184, 2655.2675965719627, 1445.6001088264184, 2655.830596571963, 1445.6001088264184, 2657.420596571963, 1445.6001088264184, 2666.8145965719627, 1449.8101088264184, 2670.3905965719628, 1451.9401088264185, 2673.974596571963, 1453.8601088264184, 2676.533596571963, 1455.6001088264184, 2676.675596571963, 1455.7901088264184, 2676.857596571963, 1456.0301088264184), (2548.531751224003, 1435.0954731549964, 2559.114905876043, 1431.6001088264184), (2548.531751224003, 1431.0954731549964, 2559.114905876043, 1431.6001088264184), (2548.531751224003, 1423.0954731549964, 2559.114905876043, 1419.6001088264184), (2548.531751224003, 1419.0954731549964, 2559.114905876043, 1415.6001088264184), (2548.531751224003, 1411.0954731549964, 2559.114905876043, 1407.6001088264184), (2559.114905876043, 1431.6001088264184, 2567.984493888275, 1431.6001088264184), (2559.114905876043, 1431.6001088264184, 2567.984493888275, 1423.6001088264184), (2559.114905876043, 1419.6001088264184, 2567.984493888275, 1419.6001088264184), (2559.114905876043, 1415.6001088264184, 2567.984493888275, 1415.6001088264184), (2559.114905876043, 1407.6001088264184, 2567.984493888275, 1403.6001088264184), (2567.984493888275, 1431.6001088264184, 2577.4785637051095, 1431.6001088264184), (2567.984493888275, 1423.6001088264184, 2577.4785637051095, 1423.6001088264184), (2567.984493888275, 1419.6001088264184, 2577.4785637051095, 1415.6001088264184), (2567.984493888275, 1415.6001088264184, 2577.4785637051095, 1411.6001088264184), (2567.984493888275, 1403.6001088264184, 2577.4785637051095, 1403.6001088264184), (2577.4785637051095, 1431.6001088264184, 2588.2013160893976, 1431.6001088264184), (2577.4785637051095, 1423.6001088264184, 2588.2013160893976, 1423.6001088264184), (2577.4785637051095, 1423.6001088264184, 2588.2013160893976, 1415.6001088264184), (2577.4785637051095, 1415.6001088264184, 2588.2013160893976, 1407.6001088264184), (2577.4785637051095, 1411.6001088264184, 2588.2013160893976, 1407.6001088264184), (2577.4785637051095, 1403.6001088264184, 2588.2013160893976, 1399.6001088264184), (2588.2013160893976, 1431.6001088264184, 2597.798842058678, 1431.6001088264184), (2588.2013160893976, 1423.6001088264184, 2597.798842058678, 1427.6001088264184), (2588.2013160893976, 1415.6001088264184, 2597.798842058678, 1423.6001088264184), (2588.2013160893976, 1407.6001088264184, 2597.798842058678, 1407.6001088264184), (2588.2013160893976, 1407.6001088264184, 2597.798842058678, 1403.6001088264184), (2588.2013160893976, 1399.6001088264184, 2597.798842058678, 1395.6001088264184), (2597.798842058678, 1431.6001088264184, 2607.842362905752, 1434.5239503797861), (2597.798842058678, 1427.6001088264184, 2607.842362905752, 1426.5239503797861), (2597.798842058678, 1423.6001088264184, 2607.842362905752, 1426.5239503797861), (2597.798842058678, 1407.6001088264184, 2607.842362905752, 1410.5239503797861), (2597.798842058678, 1403.6001088264184, 2607.842362905752, 1406.5239503797861), (2597.798842058678, 1395.6001088264184, 2607.842362905752, 1386.5239503797861), (2607.842362905752, 1434.5239503797861, 2617.0717529170083, 1436.8552636892455), (2607.842362905752, 1426.5239503797861, 2617.0717529170083, 1432.8552636892455), (2607.842362905752, 1426.5239503797861, 2617.0717529170083, 1424.8552636892455), (2607.842362905752, 1410.5239503797861, 2617.0717529170083, 1404.8552636892455), (2607.842362905752, 1406.5239503797861, 2617.0717529170083, 1400.8552636892455), (2607.842362905752, 1386.5239503797861, 2617.0717529170083, 1388.8552636892455), (2617.0717529170083, 1436.8552636892455, 2627.8066294831897, 1438.006243586899), (2617.0717529170083, 1432.8552636892455, 2627.8066294831897, 1434.006243586899), (2617.0717529170083, 1424.8552636892455, 2627.8066294831897, 1430.006243586899), (2617.0717529170083, 1404.8552636892455, 2627.8066294831897, 1410.006243586899), (2617.0717529170083, 1400.8552636892455, 2627.8066294831897, 1410.006243586899), (2617.0717529170083, 1388.8552636892455, 2627.8066294831897, 1402.006243586899), (2627.8066294831897, 1438.006243586899, 2637.720881676667, 1439.1397871271859), (2627.8066294831897, 1434.006243586899, 2637.720881676667, 1427.1397871271859), (2627.8066294831897, 1430.006243586899, 2637.720881676667, 1423.1397871271859), (2627.8066294831897, 1410.006243586899, 2637.720881676667, 1411.1397871271859), (2627.8066294831897, 1402.006243586899, 2637.720881676667, 1403.1397871271859), (2637.720881676667, 1439.1397871271859, 2648.126410539704, 1441.6001088264184), (2637.720881676667, 1427.1397871271859, 2648.126410539704, 1433.6001088264184), (2637.720881676667, 1423.1397871271859, 2648.126410539704, 1429.6001088264184), (2637.720881676667, 1411.1397871271859, 2648.126410539704, 1393.6001088264184), (2637.720881676667, 1403.1397871271859, 2648.126410539704, 1385.6001088264184), (2648.126410539704, 1441.6001088264184, 2657.704484528568, 1441.7273355985399), (2648.126410539704, 1433.6001088264184, 2657.704484528568, 1429.7273355985399), (2648.126410539704, 1429.6001088264184, 2657.704484528568, 1421.7273355985399), (2648.126410539704, 1393.6001088264184, 2657.704484528568, 1393.7273355985399), (2648.126410539704, 1385.6001088264184, 2657.704484528568, 1377.7273355985399), (2657.704484528568, 1441.7273355985399, 2667.161761375854, 1446.0168932314207), (2657.704484528568, 1429.7273355985399, 2667.161761375854, 1430.0168932314207), (2657.704484528568, 1421.7273355985399, 2667.161761375854, 1426.0168932314207), (2657.704484528568, 1393.7273355985399, 2667.161761375854, 1398.0168932314207), (2657.704484528568, 1377.7273355985399, 2667.161761375854, 1390.0168932314207), (2548.531751224003, 1439.0954731549964, 2548.531751224003, 1435.0954731549964), (2548.531751224003, 1435.0954731549964, 2548.531751224003, 1431.0954731549964), (2548.531751224003, 1431.0954731549964, 2548.531751224003, 1423.0954731549964), (2548.531751224003, 1423.0954731549964, 2548.531751224003, 1419.0954731549964), (2548.531751224003, 1419.0954731549964, 2548.531751224003, 1411.0954731549964), (2667.161761375854, 1450.0168932314207, 2667.161761375854, 1446.0168932314207), (2667.161761375854, 1446.0168932314207, 2667.161761375854, 1430.0168932314207), (2667.161761375854, 1430.0168932314207, 2667.161761375854, 1426.0168932314207), (2667.161761375854, 1426.0168932314207, 2667.161761375854, 1398.0168932314207), (2667.161761375854, 1398.0168932314207, 2667.161761375854, 1390.0168932314207)]

import math

def get_edges(coords):
    return [
        ((x1, y1), (x2, y2))  
        for polyline in coords
        for x1, y1, x2, y2 in zip(polyline[::2], polyline[1::2], polyline[2::2], polyline[3::2])
   ]

def cut_intersecting_edges(edge1, edge2):
    a, b = edge1
    c, d = edge2
    x1, y1 = a
    x2, y2 = b
    x3, y3 = c
    x4, y4 = d
    if (max(x1, x2) < min(x3, x4) or max(x3, x4) < min(x1, x2) 
           or max(y1, y2) < min(y3, y4) or max(y3, y4) < min(y1, y2)):
        # Edges are outside eachother's bounding box
        return
    tnum = (x1 - x3) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y3) * (x3 - x4)
    unum = (y1 - y2) * (x1 - x3) - (x1 - x2) * (y1 - y3)
    denom = (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4)
    if (0 <= tnum <= denom or 0 >= tnum >= denom) and (0 <= unum <= denom or 0 >= unum >= denom):
        if denom == 0:
            print("overlap")
            # overlap
            polyline = sorted([*edge1, *edge2])
            return list(zip(polyline, polyline[1:]))
        # intersection
        t = tnum / denom
        p = (x1 + t * (x2 - x1), y1 + t * (y2 - y1))
        print("split at", p)
        return [(a, p),(p, b),(c, p),(p, d)]

def normalize_edges(edgeset):
    edges = list(edgeset)
    for i, edge1 in enumerate(edges):
        if not edge1:
            continue
        a, b = edge1
        if a == b:  # A zero-length edge
            edges[i] = None  # Mark as deleted
            continue
        for j, edge2 in enumerate(edges):
            if j >= i:
                break
            if not edge2 or a in edge2 or b in edge2:
                # Consider adjacent edges as OK
                continue
            newedges = cut_intersecting_edges(edge1, edge2)
            if newedges:
                # Mark the intersecting edges as deleted
                edgeset.remove(edge1)
                edgeset.remove(edge2)
                edges[i] = edges[j] = None
                # ...and replace them with non-intersecting ones:
                edges.extend(newedges)
                edgeset.update(newedges)
                break

def direct_edges(edges):
    for i in range(len(edges)):
        edges.append(edges[i][::-1])

def create_adjacency_list(edges):
    adj = defaultdict(list)
    for edge in edges:
        adj[edge[0]].append(edge)
    return adj

def normalize_angle(angle):
    return (angle + math.tau) % math.tau

def get_areas(edges):
    adj = create_adjacency_list(edges)
    edgeset = set(edges)
    while edgeset:
        edge = next(iter(edgeset))
        path = []
        turn = 0
        while edge in edgeset:
            edgeset.remove(edge)
            a, b = edge
            angle = math.atan2(b[1] - a[1], b[0] - a[0])
            path.append(b)
            # Find index of next edge
            min_angle = 2*math.pi
            choice = 0
            for i, (_, c) in enumerate(adj[b]):
                if c == a:  # Not interested in the back-edge
                    continue
                angle2 = math.atan2(b[1] - c[1], b[0] - c[0])
                diff = normalize_angle(angle2 - angle)
                if diff < min_angle:
                    min_angle = diff
                    choice = i
            # choose that edge
            edge = adj[b][choice]
            turn += min_angle - math.pi
        if turn < 0:  # Not an outside "area"
            yield path

def get_dead_ends(adj):
    for p, neighbors in adj.items():
        if len(neighbors) == 1:  # dead end
            yield neighbors[0]
    
def lengthen_dead_ends(edgeset, grow_factor):
    adj = create_adjacency_list(edgeset)
    for short_edge in get_dead_ends(adj):
        p, q = short_edge
        # Make this edge a bit longer (data patching)
        p = (p[0] + (p[0] - q[0]) * grow_factor, 
             p[1] + (p[1] - q[1]) * grow_factor)
        edgeset.remove(short_edge)
        edgeset.remove(short_edge[::-1])
        edgeset.add((p, q))
        edgeset.add((q, p))


edges = get_edges(coords)
direct_edges(edges)
edgeset = set(edges)
lengthen_dead_ends(edgeset, 1e-10)
normalize_edges(edgeset)
areas = list(get_areas(edgeset))
print("found", len(areas), "areas")
```

Each entry in `areas` represents a path as a list of (x, y) tuples.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, it works on most of the data. However, on one example, for some reason I can't find one of the loops - https://pastebin.com/raw/aNuaJwby.

Please help me to solve this problem if you have time.

Comment: This should be faster than my version, especially if dealing with a lot of polygons.

Comment: I've updated the inputs and the picture in the post.

Comment: By deleting the original in your question, the comments below your question about specific points and edges now look strange. Can you restore the original, and then *add* the second example?

Comment: Also, your post now still says there should be 15 cycles, but I count more. It would really be better if you would restore the original, and then *add* the new example, with its particularities.

Comment: NB: I checked the new graph, and my code returns 22 areas. I verified all of them: I don't see anything wrong with it. All are accounted for.

Comment: We can open a chat room for discussion so that you understand exactly the essence of my task. I will edit the post later, after I fully understand the task. It will be better for the users

Comment: Here's the dataset with which the problem occurs - https://pastebin.com/raw/aNuaJwby. There are 9 areas, but the code only finds 8 of them

Comment: This happens because of precision issues. Your data has decimals with a fixed number of significant digits, but the place where a line crosses another may be a rational number with an infinite number of decimals, so where a line's endpoint is supposed to touch another edge *exactly*, it is actually not doing that due to limited precision in your data, leaving two possibilities: either the endpoint stretches **over** the other edge, and there is no real problem, or it is just to short, and doesn't really touch the other edge, leaving a very tiny gap in what was supposed a closed circuit.

Comment: The two problematic Y coordinates are 1439.0954731549964 and 1450.0168932314207. If you change them respectively to 1439.0954731549971 and 1450.0168932314208 the area will be closed, and the program will identify it.

Comment: I can't change the original data. I will be grateful if you fix the code so that everything works correctly.

Comment: I am unable to change the source data. I would be grateful if you could fix the code so that it works correctly. In @Krishnadev N's code this loop is located for some reason

Comment: I have updated my answer with the use of `lengthen_dead_ends`, which adjusts the input data so to counter the precision issues in the input data. Realise however that this really modifies the input, and so in theory you could have an undesired effect where edges that were *not* supposed to touch, now *do* touch. This is quite unlikely in practice, but I have to mention it. The code has a constant `1e-10` which is a factor with which dead-end edges are lengthened. This is an artificial "intervention", and you may need to use a different constant depending on your actual cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the adapted version of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78145995/5242412) to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78144684/5242412) on the same topic. You have to `snap` the lines to the points with the appropriate tolerance to deal with errors in the points of intersection which are already present in your data. Note that if you do not have the points of intersection already, you will have to find them manually and add them to the lines. This solution **DOES NOT** look for intersections, but assumes that the points are already present, except for floating point errors.

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
from shapely import geometry, ops, union_all, intersection


eps = 1.e-8


def add_intersections(coords):
    all_points  =  [geometry.Point(pair) for line in coords
                                         for pair in zip(line[::2],line[1::2])]
    point_lists = [[geometry.Point(pair) for pair in zip(line[::2],line[1::2])]
                                         for line in coords]
    lines = [geometry.LineString(line) for line in point_lists]

    for line_no in range(len(lines)):
        for point in all_points:
            lines[line_no] = ops.snap(lines[line_no], point, eps)

    return [[val for coord in line.coords for val in coord] for line in lines]


def get_cycles(coords):
    point_lists = [[pair for pair in zip(line[::2],line[1::2])] for line in coords]
    edges = [segment for point_list in point_lists
                     for segment in zip(point_list[:-1], point_list[1:])]
    G = nx.from_edgelist(edges)
    return nx.chordless_cycles(G)


def is_elementary(cycle, cycles):
    union = union_all(cycles)
    intersection_ = intersection(union, cycle)
    if intersection_.area > eps:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def elementary_filter(cycles):
    cycles = [geometry.Polygon(cycle) for cycle in cycles]
    cycles.sort(key=lambda polygon: polygon.area)
    elementary_cycles  = [cycles[0],]
    elementary_indices = [0,]
    for i in range(1, len(cycles)):
        if is_elementary(cycles[i], elementary_cycles):
            elementary_cycles.append(cycles[i])
            elementary_indices.append(i)
    return elementary_cycles, elementary_indices


def get_elementary_cycles(coords):
    coords = add_intersections(coords)
    cycles = get_cycles(coords)
    elementary_polygons, indices = elementary_filter(cycles)
    return elementary_polygons


# Make sure coords is already defined

basis_cycles = get_elementary_cycles(coords)
print('The number of basis cycles:', len(basis_cycles))
```

You can use `indices` in `get_elementary_cycles` to index the original list if you do not want to deal with `Polygon`objects. I have also added simple functions for plotting the lines and polygons:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle


def plot_lines(coords):
    line_array = [np.array([pair for pair in zip(line[::2],line[1::2])]).T
                  for line in coords]

    marker_list = ['o', 's', 'D', '^', 'v', '*', 'H', 'P', 'd']
    markers = cycle(marker_list)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for line in line_array:
        ax.plot(line[0], line[1], marker=next(markers), mfc='none', alpha=0.5)
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_title('Lines')
    return fig


def plot_polygons(polygons):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for polygon in polygons:
        x, y = polygon.exterior.xy
        ax.plot(x, y, alpha=0.5)
        ax.set_title('Polygons')
    return fig


from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from shapely.plotting import patch_from_polygon


colors = cycle(plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color'])


def plot_filled_polygons(polygons):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    patches = [patch_from_polygon(polygon) for polygon in polygons]
    color = [next(colors) for patch in patches]
    patches = PatchCollection(patches, alpha=0.5, fc=color)
    patches.set(alpha=0.5)
    ax.add_collection(patches)
    ax.set_xlim([85, 210])
    ax.set_ylim([55, 110])
    ax.set_title('Filled polygons')
    return fig


fig1 = plot_lines(coords)
fig2 = plot_polygons(basis_cycles)
fig3 = plot_filled_polygons(basis_cycles)
plt.show()
```

[image: Lines from original data]
[image: Polygons]
[image: Filled polygons]

Comment: your code produces this result - https://prnt.sc/egx4nMIqDYkQ

Here I have highlighted one of the loops. This is an incorrect output because there are more loops inside it

Comment: @BobbyLith Yes, I just realised the mistake. The network does not retain information about the spatial distribution, only the connectivity, so it only provides **one** of the possible sets of basis cycles. I have modified my answer now. I am not sure if it is optimal, but it seems to work. Please check.

Comment: It works, but not with this data - https://pastebin.com/raw/kGwpFJpj

Comment: I've updated the inputs and the picture in the post.

Comment: Your new data includes a "hole" inside a polygon. What would you want in that case?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ZXUJcelqWi08

Comment: This is implemented in @trinkot's code. However, there is an error in his code that does not recognize some loops

Comment: @BobbyLith, I want to react to this "error in his code". The error is not in my code, but in the input data that has precision issues. Please don't blame my code. I have updated my answer to "patch" the input to counter such issues.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the co-ords of **every** line intersection are specified in the input:

1. Find all polygons

```
- Construct undirected graph. 
      ( Vertices are specified in the input.  Edges are lines between vertices. )
- Construct empty list of polygons
- Loop over every vertex specified in the input
- Check if it is a member of a polygon 
        ( is there a path from the vertex that loops back again to the starting vertex.  
        Any decent graph theory library will give you a method to do this. )
- If polygon is unique, add to list of polygons
```

2. Find empty polygons

```
- Loop over vertices
   - Loop over list of polygons
     - IF vertex NOT part of polygon
         - IF vertex INSIDE polygon  
               ( algorithm https://ravenspoint.wordpress.com/2010/06/27/in-or-out/ )
               - REMOVE polygon from list of polygons 
                       ( careful not to invalidate loop iterator )
```

3. Output list of empty polygons

Note that if lines **can** cross without there being a co-ordinate specified by the input, you will have to check every pair of lines belonging to a polygon for intersection ( any computational geometry text will provide the algorithm ) and remove both polygons that are overlapping )

Comment: To be fair, a line that crossed another without a coordinate at the intersection is not a chord. It just means the graph cannot be represented in 2D without edge overlaps.

Comment: What is a chord?  The OP does not mention chords.  What has fairness got to do with it.

Comment: See @beaker's "this is probably a duplicate of..." link.

Comment: In the mean time the asker has used the term "chord" in their post, which was anyway what they were describing from the start. See [chord](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chord.html): *"a cycle chord of a graph cycle  is an edge not in  whose endpoints lie in "*